# Trim file created with `posix_fallocate`

Tags: c, linux, file-io, posix

I've opened a file for output on my Linux system using my C program, and I've had `posix_fallocate` reserve me a *bunch* of disk space for it.

More than I need, because I didn't know how much I needed.

Naively, I'd expect that when I close the file, it will be trimmed to the space I actually did need. But, of course, life isn't so easy.

So, how *do* I reserve a bunch of space for output and then trim it down to what I actually used?

Thanks!

Comment: The general idea behind `fallocate` is that if you know beforehand how large the file is going to be, you can hint the OS at it so it can give you unfragmented disk space. If you do not know, then you should not claim that you do, and just write the file sequentially.

Comment: Why do you use `posix_fallocate` ? It is very rarely useful, and probably not in your case!

Comment: @SimonRichter, I have a pretty good general idea, though I may be off by an order of kilobytes for files on the order of hundreds to thousands of megabytes.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, my program will be writing files which are hundreds to thousands of megabytes in size, typically printing data which has required significant time input to produce. The program should hold on to this data if it's unable to write the file. `posix_fallocate` would appear to provide a means of ensuring that space is available and then holding onto it. If space isn't available, my program can prompt the user for help in producing it.

Comment: There are several applications producing multi gigabytes files which never call `posix_fallocate`. You could check *approximate* available space with `statfs` or `quotactl` syscalls. With files less than a gigabyte, I won't bother...

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour is the expected one - to quote the `posix_fallocate` man page:

> ```
>    If  the  size  of  the  file  is less than offset+len, then the file is
>    increased to this size; otherwise the file size is left unchanged.
> ```

To fix the file size before closing check out `ftruncate`:

> ```
>    The  truncate()  and ftruncate() functions cause the regular
>    file named by path or referenced by fd to be truncated to  a
>    size of precisely length bytes.
> ```

Comment: And how will I know how much data I've ended up putting in the file? It may wind up there through many convoluted paths before I eventually close it.

Comment: @Richard, you could call `lseek(yourfd, 0, SEEK_CUR)` to get the current offset in your file.